# How to avoid undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I want to check if a current object's user-id is the same as the id of the current user, so I can allow some operations only to logged-in users. I am using the Devise gem to help me with authentication.

That said, I want to ask a question with a broader scope. I have build associations, at least I think so, but when I open the corresponding pages in the browser I get the error:

```
undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass
```

I know that this error often happens when a particular object in the database is not instantiated or has no entries, but I am using the console and a PostgreSQL GUI tool, to check if the data is present.

This is a screenshot https://www.evernote.com/shard/s233/sh/305c5194-87e0-4019-9eba-9a7f5d7a2839/7c89b4842cc6efc1/res/b7879832-7829-4fe3-b81a-386b6f81cc11/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832

First to clarify that I understand right, here's what some things do:

1. If you define a method (def x) within a controller's "private" section this means, that the data is only available within your controller?
2. With a callback (before_action) you populate your app's REST methods with the data of the private method, it might want to use?

Now I have an image model with:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game, inverse_of: :images
end
```

The user model reads like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :images
  has_many :games
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

In the corresponding image controller I use:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_game
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :check_user
  ...
  private

  def set_image
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_game
    @game = Game.all
  end

  def check_user
    unless (@image.user == current_user) || (current_user.admin?)
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry but you are not allowed to visit this page."
    end
  end

  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:title, :alt, :desc, :image, :category)
  end
end
```

With `@image.user` in the `check_user` method I try to get the user's id. If I only use the `current_user.admin?` it works but not as intended, obviously.

As you can see in the screenshot above, the `user_id` field is populated, so I have no idea why I get this error. Maybe I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you error message, the problem is on `@image.user` in `check_user` method. Here, `@image` is `nil`. You should check if `@image.nil?` there.

Probably change it to:

```
@image = Image.find(params[:id])
unless !@image.nil? && ((@image.user == current_user) || (current_user.admin?))
```

BTW, you should only check user in `:show, :edit, :update, :destroy` like:

```
before_action :check_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is located within the check user. But I have a valid user_id field for the images. Could it be that the authenticate user which now has no filter, does conflict with the check user?

And I added filters to the callback later on, the :show filter is not used, because I want people to be able to see individual images. In the next step, when I get this authentication to work, I plan to do different routes and pack the edit, update and destroy features in something like a backend. Thx

Comment: Yes, but the problem is `@image` is `nil` instead `@image.user` is `nil`.

Comment: That's weird, because `@image` should provide at least 4 images, the moment we speak. At least there are 4 images in the db. And if I comment out the unless-section and open the page normally, `:index` for example shows the listing with 4 images. :(

Comment: You have images in database, but you need to define what is `@image` in your method `check_user`. Otherwise, `Rails` doesn't understand what do you mean by `@image`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is something called `authorization`.

> - **Authentication** - does user exist?
> - **Authorization**  - does user have permission?

Devise provides *authentication*, whilst *authorization* has no "standard" process for Rails.

What you're asking is the base line requirement for authorization in a Rails based application. The way to fix this is to use one of the authorization gems, namely [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) to ensure the user can change the required objects.

I'd personally set up authorization as follows:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'cancancan'

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :read, Image, user_id: user.id
  end
end
```

This will allow you to simply call `can? :read, @image` to validate the authorization for the user.

---

**Fix**

The real problem you have is that you're trying to call `.user` on a **non-existent variable**.

```
for nil:NilClass
```

When you see the above error, it means that you're calling a method on an undeclared variable.

Unlike other programming languages, Ruby doesn't so much treat the variable as undeclared, but as `nil` - confusing many developers. In short, the error means you're trying to call `.user` on a variable which does not have the method present; the solution being to **ensure `@image` is declared**.

-

The error seems to be caused by this:

```
@image.user #-> @image does not exist
```

Therefore, you have to check *why* `@image` has not been declared.

I would hazard a guess that the error is caused by your `routes`. You need to make sure you're calling the `images` controller properly:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :images

#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @image = Image.find params[:id]
      authorize! :read, @image
   end
end
```

This should enable *only* users who own the image to view it. You'll not have to worry about authentication because that will be handled by Devise.

Comment: @Rick: Thank you for the insight. It was very helpful. My personal authorization logic hampered with the whole thing, I had to exclude some methods like :show and :index. The error message I posted up there was related to a situation where I was not logged in. It vanished the moment I logged back in. It would be very helpful if Rails someday could provide more insight on why an object might be "nil", on the other hand, than many developers won't use their brains to think through. I got it working in the end. That's what counts, and I learned something, too. So thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No problem! It's not Rails' responsibility to show whether a variable is `nil` - it's a `Ruby` problem. It's all because Ruby is object orientated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `respond_to?` method to check if an object can respond to a particular method before calling it. Just like this.

```
object.respond_to?(:method_name)
```